British TV-film where children befriend ghosts at a cemetry, pretty sure John Rhys-Davis was in it
Many years ago I watched a movie whose title I never knew; it's about a couple of kids who befriend the spirits of some dead people at the cemetery, among them a suffragist (who leaps in excitement when told the Prime Minister is a woman; so it must be a late-80s early-90s film) and a member of the Communist International (who resembled Rhys-Davis quite a lot; he asks at some point "Why is the Madonna singing on the radio?"). 
It looked like a direct-to-TV film, but I'm not sure about this either. Any help? Thanks a lot!!
Edit The film is definitely British; I saw it around 1999 but not as a premier or anything, it was on a cable-TV movie channel. It was in English.

Welcome to the community. Answering the following questions will help us to respond. Any other plot details? What year did you see it? What was the language? Can you estimate the year and country of production? I hope you enjoy this place as much as I have.

The film is definitely British; I saw it around 1999 but not as a premier or anything, it was on a cable-TV movie channel. It was in English. Everything else escapes me. Thanks,

@ÓscarGuajardo You can edit your question to add further details. I have done this regarding the information you gave in your previous comment.

I am pretty confident, this is "Johnny and the Dead"
It is a UK TV mini series from 1995, based on a novel from Terry Pratchett.
It is the second book in the "Johnny Maxwell" series, around Johnny and his friends Wobbler, Bigmac and Yo-less. 
Here is the plot summary from IMDb.com

If you start seeing dead people, you may have a problem... After they hear their cemetery is going to be sold as a building site, Johnny certainly has. Especially since the dead want him to stop it. And the dead are getting restless. They are not going to take this lying down; especially since it's almost Halloween... What are cemeteries for anyway? What can anyone do about anything? Will Johnny be able to stop the juggernaut of Policy and Commerce (and be in bed by ten)? 

And wiki.lspace.org lists the characters of the dead as:


Pvt. Tommy Atkins, last of the Blackbury Volunteers (the Pals)
Alderman Thomas Bowler(1826-1906)
Mr. Solomon Einstein, taxidermist and amateur physicist
Mr. Addison Fletcher, an electronics engineer
Mr. Eric Grimm (d.1927)
Mrs. Sylvia Liberty (d.1914) Suffragette
Mr. Ronald Newton (1878-1934)
Mr. Sidney "Wrong Way" Roundway, footballing legend
Comrade William Stickers a would have been Communist leader
Mr. Antonio Vicente, magician and escapologist manqué 


The Rhys-Davis lookalike would be Brian Blessed.

It adds up; everything matches... thou art a gentleman and a scholar mate! Cheers!

:) @OscarGuajardo I think it is available on YouTube, in case you want to watch it again.
